# Memory error reading a zip file in python

Tags: python, file, memory, zip

I have a thread in which I am reading a zip file with `zipfile.ZipFile().read()`, where I am getting a memory error.

I am aware that `read()` loads the entire file into memory. The size of file after unzipping is more than 100MB. I also tried with `zipfile.ZipFile().open().readlines()`, but it takes too much time.

Is there any way that I can read the file with speed without getting memory error?

Comment: `readlines()` with no `sizehint` argument also reads the entire file into memory and builds a list of the lines. So it wouldn't reduce memory requirements, but rather increase them slightly. See Aya's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're trying to read a zipped text file, you can treat the file-like object returned by [`ZipFile.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open) as an iterator, and process it line-by-line...

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip = ZipFile('myzip.zip')
stream = zip.open('myfile.txt')
for line in stream:
    do_something_with(line)
```